# Call an dialog fragment method from Activity to Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am showing one dialog fragment (showing progress ) in my activity . Calling rest api methods are in my activity . Based on rest api results , I need to some progress in the dialog fragment . So I need to call a method of dialog fragment from activity .  I tried with event bus , (Firing from Activity caught on Dialog Fragment ) - But events are not caught in dialog fragment . Is there any other solution ?

Fragment Code:

```
 public class SyncProgressFragment extends BaseDialogFragment  {

@BindView(R.id.layout_cancel)
LinearLayout layoutCancel;
@BindView(R.id.sync_with_master_breadcrumbs)
BreadcrumbsView syncWithMasterBreadCrumbs;
@BindView(R.id.master_breadcrumbs)
BreadcrumbsView masterBreadCrumbs;
@BindView(R.id.tvStep)
AppCompatTextView tvStep;
@BindView(R.id.tv_create_defect_title)
AppCompatTextView tvTitle;

private ThreadBus bus;
private FragmentManager manager;
private GoogleApiHelper googleApiHelper;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;
private boolean isOld;
private boolean isSync;
//private long requestId;
private BreadcrumbsView breadcrumbsView;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    bus = AppController.getInstance().getBus();
    bus.register(this);
    googleApiHelper =      AppController.getInstance().getGoogleApiHelper();
    googleApiHelper.reconnect();


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        isOld = bundle.getBoolean(AppConstants.IS_OLD,false);
        isSync = bundle.getBoolean(AppConstants.IS_OLD,false);
    }
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    if (isOld && isSync)
        tvTitle.setText(getString(R.string.syncing_old_data_with_bo));
    else if(!isOld && isSync)
        tvTitle.setText(getString(R.string.syncing_data_with_bo));
    else {
        tvTitle.setText(getString(R.string.downloading_master_data));
    }
    if(isSync) {
        breadcrumbsView = syncWithMasterBreadCrumbs;
        syncWithMasterBreadCrumbs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        masterBreadCrumbs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvStep.setText(getString(R.string.sending_data));
    }
    else{
        breadcrumbsView = masterBreadCrumbs;
        masterBreadCrumbs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        syncWithMasterBreadCrumbs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvStep.setText(getString(R.string.getting_master_data));

    }
}

private void initValues() {
    handler = new Handler();
}



@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    // request a window without the title
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    return dialog;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sync_progress, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    initValues();


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (bus != null) {
        bus.unregister(this);
    }
    try {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void setCancelable(boolean cancelable) {
    super.setCancelable(cancelable);
}


@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    try {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}




@OnClick({R.id.img_close, R.id.layout_cancel})
public void onViewClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.layout_cancel:
        case R.id.img_close:
            dismissAllowingStateLoss();
            break;
    }
}



@Subscribe
public void onSyncGotResponse(SyncGotResponse syncGotResponse) {
    Utilities.log(SyncProgressFragment.class,"onSyncGotResponse",""+syncGotResponse.isSuccess());
   if(syncGotResponse.isSuccess()) {
       breadcrumbsView.nextStep();
       tvStep.setText(getString(R.string.synced_data_with_bo));
   }
   else
       dismissAllowingStateLoss();
}

@Subscribe
public void onMasterGotResponse(MasterGotResponse masterGotResponse) {
    Utilities.log(SyncProgressFragment.class,"onMasterGotResponse",""+masterGotResponse.isSuccess());
    if(masterGotResponse.isSuccess()) {
        tvStep.setText(getString(R.string.downloaded_data_from_bo));
        breadcrumbsView.nextStep();
    }
    else
        dismissAllowingStateLoss();
}


 }
```

Activity Code:

```
 @Override
public void dataSyncSuccess(DataSyncResponse dataSyncResponse) {
    bus.post(new SyncGotResponse(true));

 }

  @Override
public void dataSyncFailure(String msg) {
    UiUtils.showToast(getContext(), msg);
    bus.post(new SyncGotResponse(false));
   
}


//Calling Rest Api method

if (CheckInternetConnection(getContext())) {
                try {
                    presenter.data_sync();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putBoolean(AppConstants.IS_OLD,false);
                    bundle.putBoolean(AppConstants.IS_SYNC,true);
                    syncProgressFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    syncProgressFragment.setCancelable(false);
                    syncProgressFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), syncProgressFragment.getTag());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                ShowSanckBarShow();
            }
```

Comment: Show your work. Seems like you need to use INTERFACE

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Please check the edited post